# Implementing search functionality in elastic search with exact matches showing first + with fuzziness 1 + matches with fuzziness 2 and rest

Tags: php, database, elasticsearch, nosql

Below is my code , i have to display results in the order  of 
search title with exact match + matched results with fuzziness 1 + matched results with fuzziness 2 + remaining results which are matched partially.

`{
             "size": 40,
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "in_search": 1
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "prod_id_active": 1
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "search_title": {
                              "query": "samsung galaaxy j7",
                              "fuzziness": 2,
                              "prefix_length": 1
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match": {
                            "search_title": {
                              "query": "samsung galaaxy j7",
                              "fuzziness": 2,
                              "prefix_length": 1
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "sort": {
                    "category_rank": {
                      "order": "asc"
                    },
                    "product_rank": {
                      "order": "asc"
                    }
                  }`

```
            }
```

Comment: I think you possibly want to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php